# How does the pyplot.imshow() function work?

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib

How does the `pyplot.imshow()` function work.

I have a matrix of dimensions `(20, 400)`. The matrix contains twenty images' decimal pixel values with each image of size `(20px, 20px)` (which can be seen as the second dimension of the matrix above).

This matrix was then fed to the `pyplot.imshow()` with `cmap` chosen as `gray`. I am not sure whether the function considers the second dimension elements of the image matrix as one complete image or takes into account the image distribution as `(20x20)`. I tried searching how the function takes the input matrix and performs drawing the pixel using it.

I have gone through the documentation but no luck there. It really is important to understand the implementation before using.

Comment: i wouldn't expect any software to assume that any single e.g., 20x400 array was actually a conceptual collection of several smaller arrays (with out providing it a way to interpret that unique schema).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, `pyplot.imshow()` will know nothing about the individual image dimensions, as you have it right now. It will consider your matrix as pixel values for a single image, of dimensions 20 pixels by 400 pixels, because that is the shape of your matrix. For instance:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

''' Create a matrix of random values, of shape (20,400)
I used random integer values here between 0 and 255 
but you can do the same for decimal pixel intensities '''

mat = np.random.randint(0,255,400*20).reshape(20,400)
# Call imshow:
plt.imshow(mat, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Gives you this image:

[image: full matrix]

Since your 20x20 images are essentially stored in the second dimension of the matrix, you can show an individual image, in 20x20 format (you explicitly have to reshape it, though), as such:

```
plt.imshow(mat[0,:].reshape(20,20), cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

This returns the 1st image:

[image]

For the second image, use `mat[1,:].reshape(20,20)`, etc...

**[EDIT]**: To see how `imshow()` plots your images row by row, consider the following matrix in which pixel intensities are steadily decreasing:

```
example_mat = np.linspace(1,0, 25).reshape(5,5)

>>> example_mat
array([[ 1.        ,  0.95833333,  0.91666667,  0.875     ,  0.83333333],
       [ 0.79166667,  0.75      ,  0.70833333,  0.66666667,  0.625     ],
       [ 0.58333333,  0.54166667,  0.5       ,  0.45833333,  0.41666667],
       [ 0.375     ,  0.33333333,  0.29166667,  0.25      ,  0.20833333],
       [ 0.16666667,  0.125     ,  0.08333333,  0.04166667,  0.        ]])
```

If you call `imshow()` on this matrix, you get this image:

[image: example_mat]

As you can see, the first "row" of your matrix (`example_mat[0,:]`) is the first (i.e. top) "row" of your image.

Comment: this is great but I have a code snippet to show, that does something and displays the picture in (400,) dimension rather than (20,20) distribution `plt.imshow(X[randIndex,1:].reshape(-1,20).T, cmap = 'gray')` ,

    here `X` is matrix with size `(5000,401)` and `randIndex` are `100` 
    random indices to pick from `X` and display them

Comment: my goal is to understand how this code works, and how is the `pyplot.imshow()` function treating the inputs given to it.

Comment: @mohitR0_0 as the answer states, imshow displays the array in origin layout of the array. In other words, the value at array[5, 5] is shown as a pixel at y=4, x=5. The origin (0, 0) is in the upper left corner by default.

Comment: In that case, `plt.imshow` is simply going to show you an image of the dimensions of your matrix (20 pixels by 400 pixels, or whatever your matrix size is). If your matrix is of size (20,400), it is as I showed, if it is (20,400,3), then it will be a 20 by 400 pixel image with 3 channels (red, green, blue), and if it shape (20,400,4), then it will be 4 channels (red, green, blue, alpha). Any other value in the third dimension will not work.

Comment: I am getting it now, are the pixels drawn, starting from the `upper left corner` to the last pixel drawn at the `lower right corner`. I mean are the pixels drawn in `row major` order?

Comment: why the downvote to the question though, these downvotes prevents the potential askers to stop asking questions, most importantly if they are beginners, I researched a lot about this issue and then finally decided to ask it here in stackoverflow but recieved a downvote and later will be banned from asking, not good; but thanks for helping me all the way, thank you so much

Comment: See my edit, I explained the row-by-row thing. Also, please don't assume you know who downvoted your question (fyi, it was not me). I would assume they did so because of a lack of a [MCVE], but I can't know for sure.

Comment: amazing answer, thanks for helping, accepting it, but a word though : this community is getting stronger due to all these new beginners who are added daily and that they are treated as noobs all the way and later banned from community, nevermind, thank you so much for the answer, albeit.